# Array initialization in F#

Tags: arrays, f#, initialization

How do I create and initialize an array in F# based on a given record type?
Suppose I want to create an Array of 100 record1 records.

e.g.

```
type record1 = {
  value1:string;
  value2:string
}

let myArray = Array.init 100 ?
```

But it appears the Array.init does not allow for this, is there a way to do this?

Edited to add:

Of course I could do something like this:

```
let myArray = [|for i in 0..99 -> { value1="x"; value2="y" }|]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do what you need. Hope it helps.

```
type record1 = {
  value1:string;
  value2:string
}

let myArray  = Array.init 100 (fun x -> {value1 = "x"; value2 = "y"})
```

or using Generics

```
let myArray  = Array.init<record1> 100 (fun x -> {value1 = "x"; value2 = "y"})
```

Comment: This is not as efficient as the answer using `Array.create`, which only has to create a single record object instead of creating 100 separate objects. Since F# records are immutable, there are no drawbacks since that object's value will never change. (See my comment on the `Array.create` answer for more details.)

Answer (score 13):

You can use also `Array.create`, which creates an array of a given size, with all its elements initialized to a defined value:

```
let myArray  = Array.create 100 {value1="x"; value2="y"}
```

Give a look to this list of  [array operations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp.core/microsoft.fsharp.collections.array.html).

Comment: Are you sure about this? For me this created an array of 100 items all pointing to the same record. So if i say myArray.[5].value1 <- 100, then myArray.[10].value1 would also return 100 because there was just one actual record (I suspect). When I used Array.init 100 (fun x-> {value1="x"; value2="y"}) it worked as expected.

Comment: @gjvdkamp - Except that since F# records are immutable by default, there's absolutely no problem with an array of 100 items all pointing to the same record, unless you've created a record with mutable fields. (Which is usually a bad idea, for too many reasons to go into in a single comment). If your record is immutable, the compiler won't let you do `myArray.[5].value1 <- 100`; instead, you'd be doing `myArray.[5].value1 = { myArray.[5] with value1 = 100 }`, which creates a *new object* and assigns it to that array position. See https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/records/ for more.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can create a sequence, instead of creating an array, like this:

```
// nItems, given n and an item, returns a sequence of item repeated n times
let rec nItems n item = 
  seq {
    match n with
    | n when n > 0 -> yield item; yield! nItems (n - 1) item
    | _ -> ()
  }

type Fnord =
 { foo: int }

printfn "%A" (nItems 99999999 {foo = 3})
// seq [{foo = 3;}; {foo = 3;}; {foo = 3;}; {foo = 3;}; ...]

printfn "%A" (nItems 3 3 |> Seq.toArray)
[|3; 3; 3|]
```

The nice thing about the sequence, instead of an array, is that it creates items as you need them, rather than all at once.  And it's simple to go back and forth between sequences and arrays if you need to.