# Functional approach to initialising classes

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am new to F# so am keen on trying to approach problems in a more functional way (rather than with the imperative thinking I am used to).

For this problem, I am reading data in from Excel which contains ~ 6000 lines of data with a number of fields (age, sex, gender etc.).

I am using a class to store these data points in - extract below:

```
type datastore(array:obj[,], row)=
    let id=array.[row,1]:?> string;
    let gender=array.[row,2] :?> string;
    let sex = array.[row,3] :?> string;
    //...continues for a number of other cases
```

I am currently initialising these classes with the following code which works fine, but is an imperative approach:

```
let DataPoints = 
    let DataInput = //function to read data in from Excel
    [for i in DataInput.GetLowerBound(0) .. DataInput.GetUpperBound(0) -> 
        new datastore(DataInput,i)]
```

My question is, how can I do this in a more functional way?

I have tried the following (which does not work: error given is simply 'Stopped due to error').

```
let num = DataInput.GetUpperBound(0)
let MPs3 = Array.init  num (fun x -> new datastore(DataInput,x))
```

I have also looked at the following links, which did not seem to help completely.

[Array initialization in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115281/array-initialization-in-f?rq=1)

[How to define a record field as an array in f#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150233/how-to-define-a-record-field-as-an-array-in-f?rq=1)

Comment: Use ExcelProvider: http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Did you have any more general guidance for my specific problem if I were to continue with my current approach?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Why do you think it's imperative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional programming is one of those things that everyone has their own private definition of. If you ask me, two qualities that stand out are:

- thinking about things in terms of types (call it type-driven, type-first programming or whatever),
- thinking of your logic as a data transformation pipeline made of composable steps.

So if I had a problem like yours, I'd first define a strongly typed representation of the data. Records are better suited than classes to storing "dumb" data, so that's what I'd use:

```
type DataPoint = 
    {
        Id:     string
        Gender: GenderType
        Sex:    SexType
    }
    static member FromRow(row: obj []) = 
        {
            Id     = row.[0] :?> string
            Gender = GenderType.Parse <| (row.[1] :?> string)
            Sex    = SexType.Parse <| (row.[2] :?> string)
        }
```

For a proper representation, `Gender` and `Sex` should really be discriminated unions with `Parse` functions rather than strings, but I'll leave defining them as an exercise for the reader ;)

Once you have a way of turning a row in the array into a `DataPoint`, you need to actually get the rows. For that, let's cut the 2d array you get from Excel into a sequence of rows. There's no standard function to do that, but it should look roughly like this:

```
module Array2D = 
    let intoRows (arr: obj[,]) : seq<obj []> = 
        seq { for x in 0 .. Array2D.length1 arr - 1 do
                  yield [| for y in 0 .. Array2D.length2 arr - 1 -> arr.[x, y] |]}
```

With this, we have everything we need, so now just put them together into a pipeline:

```
let dataPoints = 
    let input = //function to read data in from Excel
    input
    |> Array2D.intoRows
    |> Seq.map DataPoint.FromRow
    |> Array.ofSeq
```

This makes it easy to see what's going on. You can easily dissect your data at each step, and extending the code is simple. For instance, if you want to turn each of those records into a class (e.g. a viewmodel), that's just another `map` step to add here.

Comment: Sex and gender are each too complicated to handle properly with a discriminated union. In most cases, it's best just not to deal with them at all!

Answer (score 2):

I'd not put it as "less, or more functional". `DataPoints` in your second snippet is a **list** of `datastore`values initialized by F# [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#F.23) mechanism.

If you want `DataPoints` to be instead an **array** of `datastore`values initialized by standard library function [`Array.init`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee370582.aspx) the correspondent code may look like

```
let DataPoints =
   let (il,ih) = (DataInput.GetLowerBound(0),DataInput.GetUpperBound(0)) in
   Array.init (ih - il + 1) (fun x -> new datastore(DataInput, x + il))
```

in order to adopt given `Array.init` element index handling from `0` to `number of elements - 1` to required one from `DataInput.GetLowerBound(0)` to `DataInput.GetUpperBound(0) - DataInput.GetLowerBound(0)`.

But both approaches are forms of functional programming comprehensions for generating sequences of elements.

Comment: This is what I'd do if I wanted to use `Array.init`, but it is worth noting that, in this case, the list comprehension just looks a lot simpler :-)